# пропадает bacground url если удалить img

Tags: css

Подскажите по какой причине может быть такое
Если закоментить img то bacgroun url пропадает а если оставлять то отображается фоном
(Хотелось бы оставить только bacground url)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
закоментила img

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
результат после того как закоментила

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
раскоментила

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
результат после того как раскоментила

Answer (score 1):

Высота `div` тега зависит от его контента. Когда вы убираете его содержимое, его высота становится равна нулю, т.е. у него всё ещё есть `background-image`, но из-за нулевой высоты она попросту не отображается.

Один из вариантов решения - сделать высоту вашего `div`'а ненулевой с помощью `css` свойств (`height`, `min-height`).

Comment: глупо что об этом не подумала, благодарю)